# "Fold-out" for row in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

Java 8, min SDK: 24, target SDK: 27

My app displays a map with some type of map marker (within a `Fragment`) and if I click on one of these markers, a popup comes up to show some additional information about this marker. Currently I'm using a normal `AlertDialog` for that but I might replace it with a `DialogFragment` in the future.

Inside the dialog there's a `RecyclerView` that is filled with multiple values. If I click on one of the rows, I want my app to open a "fold-out" underneath it (the other rows should move down) that displays even more information about that row. Clicking on the row again should close that "fold-out".

Similar to what the [FoldingCell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) library does but I want to add to the original row (instead of replacing it) and also don't need the fancy animation.

Like this:

[image]

Is "fold-out" the right word for it? I'm pretty sure I saw a similar question here on Stackoverflow (might have been for iOS) a while back but I've not been able to find it again yet. I know how to do the whole `onClick` thing for the map and the `RecyclerView` but how do I accomplish the "fold-out" part (create design in xml, then load via Java class)?

Comment: Perhaps once you click an item, change it's itemType, and make your RecyclerView work for multiple item types? From what i see you'd need a `NORMAL` and `EXPANDED` item types. Both using different XML layouts. And filled with different data in `onBindViewHolder()`.

the OnClickListener would simply change the clicked item's type.

Comment: @Shark Sorry for the late reply. So override `getItemViewType`, which then either returns `NORMAL` or `EXPANDED` and use that and a `notifyDataSetChanged()` to load a different version of the view in `onBindViewHolder()` on click? Is that approach the same as using a `boolean[]` that keeps track of what row is currently expanded? Is there a way to do this without having to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`? I've read multiple posts here on Stackexchange that say that that is an expensive operation.

Comment: why not just update the item that was clicked instead of everything?

Comment: @Shark With `notifyItemChanged`? Good idea! Is it okay to call that for multiple rows though? There should only be a single row expanded at any time, which means that I have to load the `NORMAL` item type for the row that was expanded last. For that I created a `boolean[numberOfRows]` that remembers which row is currently expanded.

Comment: @Shark I just tested your suggestion by first changing the previous row back, then updating the new one but I noticed something (that obviously makes sense with how a `RecyclerView` works): If the `RecyclerView` is pretty small and I expand the first row, then scroll down and expand the last one, it doesn't scroll up, so it looks like the very first row isn't "folded" in if it's off-screen at the moment. If I then scroll up, it shows up as folded. `notifyDataSetChanged` won't do this "fold-in" either. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: make the boolean "fold-out" a property of the backing dataset item. but it would be much more beneficial if this discussion is continued after posting some code.

Comment: The whole "fold out" part is working (apart from the mentioned visual problem) but I came across a different problem that I have to fix first, so I've not had time to post the working code as an answer, sorry. I'm going to "@" you once I have more time for this part again, if that's okay.