# Wrap text to next line in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, textview, word-wrap

My app (min API 24, target API 27) has a `RecyclerView` inside an `AlertDialog` that automatically sets its width (I don't touch it). Clicking on a row loads its expanded version (I change the layout in `onBindViewHolder` according to `holder.getItemViewType()`) - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61818692/2016165) question for images. The expanded row looks like this:

- LinearLayout1 (vertical)

  - LinearLayout2 (horizontal)

    - TextView1
    - TextView2
  - TextView3

The XML for `TextView3` looks like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="20dp"
android:paddingStart="20dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:text="TextView3"
android:textColor="@color/colorText"
android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

The problem is: I set the text at runtime (each `TextView3` has its own text) and it doesn't wrap into the next line if it's a long text (doesn't matter if it's multiple words or just one). Instead the `AlertDialog` gets wider to make it fit in a single line. If the text is very, very long and can't fit in a single line, the text wraps BUT the `TextView`s in the rows that aren't expanded (they use `layout_weight` and `layout_width="0dp"`) change width too and some of their text is then even cut off/not visible anymore.

What I've tried (in different variations):

```
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:singleLine="false"
```

The only result was that in a couple of variations the `AlertDialog`'s width either shrinks again once the row isn't expanded any more or it always stays the same, once it's changed.

This seems to be somehow connected to setting the `RecyclerView`'s `android:layout_height="300dp"`: If I change it back to `wrap_content`, the `AlertDialog`'s width still changes and the height isn't limited either but all the `TextView`s look normal.

How do I make `TextView3` wrap its text into the next line, without changing the width of the `AlertDialog` or messing with the other `TextView`s?

Comment: Can you share your current screenshort

Comment: @Kabilan There's an image in the other question I linked. ;)

Comment: Other way you should use scrollview in your view header

Comment: @Kabilan Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I don't use a header because it's an `AlertDialog` and its title (or the buttons) isn't affected by this other layout anyway.

Comment: you dont yous custom dialog box...? . Can you share your code..? else

<S>
<L>
<Your XML Inside>
<L>
<S>
My Idea . Its adjust only changed inside of the dialog box. dont affect dialog box height

Comment: I simply use an `AlertDialog` and set its layout (so the space between the title and the buttons) to a custom layout that contains the `RecyclerView`, using `alertDialogBuilder.setView(specialDialogView);`. That's it. The `RecyclerView` I set up as you would usually set one up, there's nothing special about that.

Comment: What are `<S>` and `<L>`? I'm fine with the content changing the dialog's height, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see more than 2 or 3 rows. I just don't want it to become too huge, that's why I limit the `RecyclerView`'s height. The problem isn't the height though but that `TextView3` changes the dialog's width, which I don't understand.

Comment: <S> Means Scroll view . <L> Means Linear layout

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--<YOUR XML INSERT HERE ></YOUR>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Why do you add a `ScrollView`? The `RecyclerView` scrolls on its own, there's no need for an extra one. I'm afraid you misunderstood me: The problem isn't the height, it's the width that is changed, even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Understood bro. but u need scroll, expandable and no wide the dialog

Comment: I think I know now what you mean: Are you suggesting a `ScrollView` because if `TextView3` gets wider inside, it only shows the scroll bar instead of making the dialog wider too? That's not what the question is though, it's `How do I make TextView3 wrap its text into the next line...`, which means: I want to get rid of the problem completely (-> `TextView3` wraps its text properly and doesn't change width), not work around the effects (-> use a `ScrollView`).